# Data type of object style property value

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider this:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input'),
  khaki = document.getElementById('khaki'),
  dataType = document.getElementById('dataType');
input.oninput = function() {
  khaki.style.flexGrow = 10 - this.value;
  dataType.textContent = 'Data type: ' + typeof khaki.style.flexGrow;
};
```

```css
main {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
  display: flex;
}
main div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div style="background-color:coral;"></div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;"></div>
  <div style="background-color:khaki;" id="khaki"></div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;"></div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgrey;"></div>
</main>

<input type="number" id="input" value="9" max="9">
<span id="dataType"></span>
```

I wonder why it shows the data type of the flex-row property value as `string`, but if you replace `khaki.style.flexGrow` with its equivalent `10 - this.value`:

```
dataType.textContent = 'Data type: ' + typeof (10 - this.value);
```

it will show the data type as `number`.
Can I generalize it and conclude that all objects style property values and all elements attribute values are strings?

Comment: The actual value is a string, but your (10 - ...) casts the result to a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all styles (or that matter all attributes) are stored as string. Since all styles are stored in one string which is then parsed into individual styles.

simply because `10-"1"` is `9` i.e. both the operands `10` and `"1"` are converted to numbers first and then subtraction happens, which is why you get a number `9` as a result.

but `"1"` by itself is a `string`

Comment: The same comment as the one given on Kiril's answer.

Comment: @Mori attribute values are always stored as string. But if you store it in a variable and check that variable type instead of checking khaki.style.flexGrow type, it will show as numeric.

Comment: @Mori check the updated answer to address your updated question.

Answer (score 1):

If in short - because you're subtracting a string from a number. And according to [The Subtraction Operator algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.2) both operands are converted to Numbers.

```
1. Let lref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
3. Let rref be the result of evaluating MultiplicativeExpression.
4. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
5. Let lnum be ToNumber(lval). //conversion of 10 to number
6. Let rnum be ToNumber(rval). //conversion of this.value (e.g. "1") string to number
7. Return the result of applying the subtraction operation to lnum and rnum.
```

Comment: How about `khaki.style.flexGrow`? Why is its value data type is shown as `string`? Can I generalize it to all object style property values and know them as `string`?

Comment: I'd say that's how `flex-grow` works. According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-grow.asp) in JS world flexGrow value is a string: `object.style.flexGrow="5"`

Comment: And well yes, seems that all `style`-s are strings https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style